# Exporting java project to jar changed access modifiers

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, access-modifiers

I have problem. Recently I exported project written not by me, so I cann't slap it here :/, to a JAR file. It's because I want to use it in my project. The problem i met is that doing it in eclipse changed access modifier of constructor in one important class. Because of that different method also from this exported project, so it's immutable, can't access it and throws an IllegalAccessError. Is there a way, to block that change while exporting? Did I made something wrong?

EDIT:

```
public class ClassOne extends ClassOneParent {

    private final Logger logger;

    protected ClassOne(final Conf configuration,
                                  final Logger logger) {
        super(configuration);
        this.logger = logger;
    }

}
```

So this is a class that has a constructor I need to access.

```
public abstract class ClassTwo extends ClassTwoParent {

    protected static ReturnedTypeINeed getReturnedType(final Logger logger) {
        final Conf configuration = new Conf();
        return new ClassOne(configuration, logger).getService();
    }
}
```

So ClassTwo has a method that tries to access
in return ClassOne constructor. Normally there is an public modifier for ClassOne constructor and everything works, after exporting to jar it changed to protected. Is there a way to bypass it? ClassTwo also is a part of the jar so I can't modify it.

EDIT Two:
It's the same jar, but different package, that is why it throws IllegalAccessError, I made a jar from a big project with multiple subprojects. That is important and I forgot to mention.

Comment: It's fine that you "can't slap it here", but you still need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Eclipse doesn't just 'change access modifiers' -  you need to explain exactly what is happening.

Comment: The problem is, I know only that the original file has a public modifier before constructor, and after I did export project to .jar it changed to protected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to directly call `ClassTwo.getReturnedType(logger)` from outside the jar that won't work because it is protected and therefore not accessible. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with your posted example code. If `ClassTwo` is in the same jar it should be able to call `ClassOne(...)`

Comment: It's the same jar, but different package, that is why it throws IllegalAccessError, I made a jar from a big project with multiple subprojects.

Comment: Ok, then protected is only accessible from the same package or from a subclass in another package.